# How to prevent user from using non english alphabet characters like “š, č, ć, ž, đ ... etc” in user name?

Tags: php, character-encoding, preg-match, non-english

i want to prevent users in the registration field of username from using non-english characters.

I have this code :

```
if (preg_match('/[^\p{Arabic}\p{Latin}\d ]/u', $name)) return t('The username contains characters different than latin and arabic characters');
```

but it only prevent characters like : _ - ()!@#$%^":><.... and not characters like š, č, ć, ž, đ ...

i want a code that do that without effect on arabic characters or something.

please help

Comment: Why restrict: the English language uses some of those more unusual characters as well naïve, fiancée

Comment: simply preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]*$/gi', $name); will do

Comment: @SankalpBhatt ... except that will not allow Arabic at all! (Also the `/g` is superfluous here.)

Comment: becouse i don't want a user to use username like "Želda" and someone else use " Zelda" they gonna looks the same user while they are not !! .. i don't want to confuse people

Comment: @tripleee He only needs English alphabets not Arabic. So a simple regular expression like: '/^[a-z0-9]*$/gi' seems enough.

Comment: no i want users to use both arabic and english aplphabets and numbers but nothing else.

Comment: Be careful though, that the arabic letter "ا" also looks similar to an "I" or "l" (somewhat, depending on the font). Same for "ـا" and "L". Besides, "Zelda" and "ZeIda" are also very similar (both only latin characters).

Comment: Agree with @knittle. I think you are fixing the wrong problem, or you are fixing it in the wrong way. If there even is a problem at all. The Latin alphabet also contains all those diacritics. Plain English != Latin.

Comment: But by now, you probably have found out a way to combine `{arabic}` with @SankalpBhatt's suggestion of `[a-z]` in your regular expression..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function to check if the username is arabic:

```
function isArabic($str)
{
    return preg_match('/^\p{Arabic}*$/u', $str);
}
```

**example**:

```
var_dump(isArabic('الق'));

var_dump(isArabic('القd')); // 0 since it contains 'd'
```

To validate username in your case I would do:

```
function isValidUsername($username)
{
    return (preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/', $username) || isArabic($username));
}
```

Or you could just this regex:

```
'/(?:^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$)|(?:^\p{Arabic}+(?:[ _-]\p{Arabic}+)*$)/u'
```

**[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gV7cP2/1)**

**example**:

```
var_dump(isValidUsername('Želda')); // false
var_dump(isValidUsername('Zel-da')); // true
var_dump(isValidUsername('Zelda whaever,.')); // false
var_dump(isValidUsername('الق')); // true
var_dump(isValidUsername('الق.الق')); // false
var_dump(isValidUsername('القd')); // false
```

However instead of preventing user from using non english characters you might want to convert it using this function:

```
function toAscii($input)
{
    $str = html_entity_decode($input,ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8");
    $oldLocale = setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 0);  
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');
    $str = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $str);
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, $oldLocale);
    return $str;
}
```

It will return the converted string.

**example**:

```
echo toAscii('Želda'); // Zelda
```

For that I also like to use the function remove_accents form Wordpress:

```
/**
 * Converts all accent characters to ASCII characters.
 *
 * If there are no accent characters, then the string given is just returned.
 *
 * @since 1.2.1
 *
 * @param string $string Text that might have accent characters
 * @return string Filtered string with replaced "nice" characters.
 */
function remove_accents($string, $locale = null) {
    if ( !preg_match('/[\x80-\xff]/', $string) )
        return $string;

    if (seems_utf8($string)) {
        $chars = array(
        // Decompositions for Latin-1 Supplement
        chr(194).chr(170) => 'a', chr(194).chr(186) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(128) => 'A', chr(195).chr(129) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(130) => 'A', chr(195).chr(131) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(132) => 'A', chr(195).chr(133) => 'A',
        chr(195).chr(134) => 'AE',chr(195).chr(135) => 'C',
        chr(195).chr(136) => 'E', chr(195).chr(137) => 'E',
        chr(195).chr(138) => 'E', chr(195).chr(139) => 'E',
        chr(195).chr(140) => 'I', chr(195).chr(141) => 'I',
        chr(195).chr(142) => 'I', chr(195).chr(143) => 'I',
        chr(195).chr(144) => 'D', chr(195).chr(145) => 'N',
        chr(195).chr(146) => 'O', chr(195).chr(147) => 'O',
        chr(195).chr(148) => 'O', chr(195).chr(149) => 'O',
        chr(195).chr(150) => 'O', chr(195).chr(153) => 'U',
        chr(195).chr(154) => 'U', chr(195).chr(155) => 'U',
        chr(195).chr(156) => 'U', chr(195).chr(157) => 'Y',
        chr(195).chr(158) => 'TH',chr(195).chr(159) => 's',
        chr(195).chr(160) => 'a', chr(195).chr(161) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(162) => 'a', chr(195).chr(163) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(164) => 'a', chr(195).chr(165) => 'a',
        chr(195).chr(166) => 'ae',chr(195).chr(167) => 'c',
        chr(195).chr(168) => 'e', chr(195).chr(169) => 'e',
        chr(195).chr(170) => 'e', chr(195).chr(171) => 'e',
        chr(195).chr(172) => 'i', chr(195).chr(173) => 'i',
        chr(195).chr(174) => 'i', chr(195).chr(175) => 'i',
        chr(195).chr(176) => 'd', chr(195).chr(177) => 'n',
        chr(195).chr(178) => 'o', chr(195).chr(179) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(180) => 'o', chr(195).chr(181) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(182) => 'o', chr(195).chr(184) => 'o',
        chr(195).chr(185) => 'u', chr(195).chr(186) => 'u',
        chr(195).chr(187) => 'u', chr(195).chr(188) => 'u',
        chr(195).chr(189) => 'y', chr(195).chr(190) => 'th',
        chr(195).chr(191) => 'y', chr(195).chr(152) => 'O',
        // Decompositions for Latin Extended-A
        chr(196).chr(128) => 'A', chr(196).chr(129) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(130) => 'A', chr(196).chr(131) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(132) => 'A', chr(196).chr(133) => 'a',
        chr(196).chr(134) => 'C', chr(196).chr(135) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(136) => 'C', chr(196).chr(137) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(138) => 'C', chr(196).chr(139) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(140) => 'C', chr(196).chr(141) => 'c',
        chr(196).chr(142) => 'D', chr(196).chr(143) => 'd',
        chr(196).chr(144) => 'D', chr(196).chr(145) => 'd',
        chr(196).chr(146) => 'E', chr(196).chr(147) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(148) => 'E', chr(196).chr(149) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(150) => 'E', chr(196).chr(151) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(152) => 'E', chr(196).chr(153) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(154) => 'E', chr(196).chr(155) => 'e',
        chr(196).chr(156) => 'G', chr(196).chr(157) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(158) => 'G', chr(196).chr(159) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(160) => 'G', chr(196).chr(161) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(162) => 'G', chr(196).chr(163) => 'g',
        chr(196).chr(164) => 'H', chr(196).chr(165) => 'h',
        chr(196).chr(166) => 'H', chr(196).chr(167) => 'h',
        chr(196).chr(168) => 'I', chr(196).chr(169) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(170) => 'I', chr(196).chr(171) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(172) => 'I', chr(196).chr(173) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(174) => 'I', chr(196).chr(175) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(176) => 'I', chr(196).chr(177) => 'i',
        chr(196).chr(178) => 'IJ',chr(196).chr(179) => 'ij',
        chr(196).chr(180) => 'J', chr(196).chr(181) => 'j',
        chr(196).chr(182) => 'K', chr(196).chr(183) => 'k',
        chr(196).chr(184) => 'k', chr(196).chr(185) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(186) => 'l', chr(196).chr(187) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(188) => 'l', chr(196).chr(189) => 'L',
        chr(196).chr(190) => 'l', chr(196).chr(191) => 'L',
        chr(197).chr(128) => 'l', chr(197).chr(129) => 'L',
        chr(197).chr(130) => 'l', chr(197).chr(131) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(132) => 'n', chr(197).chr(133) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(134) => 'n', chr(197).chr(135) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(136) => 'n', chr(197).chr(137) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(138) => 'n', chr(197).chr(139) => 'N',
        chr(197).chr(140) => 'O', chr(197).chr(141) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(142) => 'O', chr(197).chr(143) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(144) => 'O', chr(197).chr(145) => 'o',
        chr(197).chr(146) => 'OE',chr(197).chr(147) => 'oe',
        chr(197).chr(148) => 'R',chr(197).chr(149) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(150) => 'R',chr(197).chr(151) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(152) => 'R',chr(197).chr(153) => 'r',
        chr(197).chr(154) => 'S',chr(197).chr(155) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(156) => 'S',chr(197).chr(157) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(158) => 'S',chr(197).chr(159) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(160) => 'S', chr(197).chr(161) => 's',
        chr(197).chr(162) => 'T', chr(197).chr(163) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(164) => 'T', chr(197).chr(165) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(166) => 'T', chr(197).chr(167) => 't',
        chr(197).chr(168) => 'U', chr(197).chr(169) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(170) => 'U', chr(197).chr(171) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(172) => 'U', chr(197).chr(173) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(174) => 'U', chr(197).chr(175) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(176) => 'U', chr(197).chr(177) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(178) => 'U', chr(197).chr(179) => 'u',
        chr(197).chr(180) => 'W', chr(197).chr(181) => 'w',
        chr(197).chr(182) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(183) => 'y',
        chr(197).chr(184) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(185) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(186) => 'z', chr(197).chr(187) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(188) => 'z', chr(197).chr(189) => 'Z',
        chr(197).chr(190) => 'z', chr(197).chr(191) => 's',
        // Decompositions for Latin Extended-B
        chr(200).chr(152) => 'S', chr(200).chr(153) => 's',
        chr(200).chr(154) => 'T', chr(200).chr(155) => 't',
        // Euro Sign
        chr(226).chr(130).chr(172) => 'E',
        // GBP (Pound) Sign
        chr(194).chr(163) => '',
        // Vowels with diacritic (Vietnamese)
        // unmarked
        chr(198).chr(160) => 'O', chr(198).chr(161) => 'o',
        chr(198).chr(175) => 'U', chr(198).chr(176) => 'u',
        // grave accent
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(166) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(167) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(176) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(177) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(128) => 'E', chr(225).chr(187).chr(129) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(146) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(147) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(156) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(157) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(170) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(171) => 'u',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(178) => 'Y', chr(225).chr(187).chr(179) => 'y',
        // hook
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(162) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(163) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(168) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(169) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(178) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(179) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(186) => 'E', chr(225).chr(186).chr(187) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(130) => 'E', chr(225).chr(187).chr(131) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(136) => 'I', chr(225).chr(187).chr(137) => 'i',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(142) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(143) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(148) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(149) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(158) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(159) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(166) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(167) => 'u',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(172) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(173) => 'u',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(182) => 'Y', chr(225).chr(187).chr(183) => 'y',
        // tilde
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(170) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(171) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(180) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(181) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(188) => 'E', chr(225).chr(186).chr(189) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(132) => 'E', chr(225).chr(187).chr(133) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(150) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(151) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(160) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(161) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(174) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(175) => 'u',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(184) => 'Y', chr(225).chr(187).chr(185) => 'y',
        // acute accent
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(164) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(165) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(174) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(175) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(190) => 'E', chr(225).chr(186).chr(191) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(144) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(145) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(154) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(155) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(168) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(169) => 'u',
        // dot below
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(160) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(161) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(172) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(173) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(182) => 'A', chr(225).chr(186).chr(183) => 'a',
        chr(225).chr(186).chr(184) => 'E', chr(225).chr(186).chr(185) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(134) => 'E', chr(225).chr(187).chr(135) => 'e',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(138) => 'I', chr(225).chr(187).chr(139) => 'i',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(140) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(141) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(152) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(153) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(162) => 'O', chr(225).chr(187).chr(163) => 'o',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(164) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(165) => 'u',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(176) => 'U', chr(225).chr(187).chr(177) => 'u',
        chr(225).chr(187).chr(180) => 'Y', chr(225).chr(187).chr(181) => 'y',
        // Vowels with diacritic (Chinese, Hanyu Pinyin)
        chr(201).chr(145) => 'a',
        // macron
        chr(199).chr(149) => 'U', chr(199).chr(150) => 'u',
        // acute accent
        chr(199).chr(151) => 'U', chr(199).chr(152) => 'u',
        // caron
        chr(199).chr(141) => 'A', chr(199).chr(142) => 'a',
        chr(199).chr(143) => 'I', chr(199).chr(144) => 'i',
        chr(199).chr(145) => 'O', chr(199).chr(146) => 'o',
        chr(199).chr(147) => 'U', chr(199).chr(148) => 'u',
        chr(199).chr(153) => 'U', chr(199).chr(154) => 'u',
        // grave accent
        chr(199).chr(155) => 'U', chr(199).chr(156) => 'u',
        );


        if ( 'de_DE' == $locale ) {
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(132) ] = 'Ae';
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(164) ] = 'ae';
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(150) ] = 'Oe';
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(182) ] = 'oe';
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(156) ] = 'Ue';
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(188) ] = 'ue';
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(159) ] = 'ss';
        } elseif ( 'da_DK' === $locale ) {
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(134) ] = 'Ae';
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(166) ] = 'ae';
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(152) ] = 'Oe';
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(184) ] = 'oe';
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(133) ] = 'Aa';
            $chars[ chr(195).chr(165) ] = 'aa';
        }

        $string = strtr($string, $chars);
    } else {
        // Assume ISO-8859-1 if not UTF-8
        $chars['in'] = chr(128).chr(131).chr(138).chr(142).chr(154).chr(158)
            .chr(159).chr(162).chr(165).chr(181).chr(192).chr(193).chr(194)
            .chr(195).chr(196).chr(197).chr(199).chr(200).chr(201).chr(202)
            .chr(203).chr(204).chr(205).chr(206).chr(207).chr(209).chr(210)
            .chr(211).chr(212).chr(213).chr(214).chr(216).chr(217).chr(218)
            .chr(219).chr(220).chr(221).chr(224).chr(225).chr(226).chr(227)
            .chr(228).chr(229).chr(231).chr(232).chr(233).chr(234).chr(235)
            .chr(236).chr(237).chr(238).chr(239).chr(241).chr(242).chr(243)
            .chr(244).chr(245).chr(246).chr(248).chr(249).chr(250).chr(251)
            .chr(252).chr(253).chr(255);

        $chars['out'] = "EfSZszYcYuAAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiinoooooouuuuyy";

        $string = strtr($string, $chars['in'], $chars['out']);
        $double_chars['in'] = array(chr(140), chr(156), chr(198), chr(208), chr(222), chr(223), chr(230), chr(240), chr(254));
        $double_chars['out'] = array('OE', 'oe', 'AE', 'DH', 'TH', 'ss', 'ae', 'dh', 'th');
        $string = str_replace($double_chars['in'], $double_chars['out'], $string);
    }

    return $string;
}

    /**
 * Set the mbstring internal encoding to a binary safe encoding when func_overload
 * is enabled.
 *
 * When mbstring.func_overload is in use for multi-byte encodings, the results from
 * strlen() and similar functions respect the utf8 characters, causing binary data
 * to return incorrect lengths.
 *
 * This function overrides the mbstring encoding to a binary-safe encoding, and
 * resets it to the users expected encoding afterwards through the
 * `reset_mbstring_encoding` function.
 *
 * It is safe to recursively call this function, however each
 * `mbstring_binary_safe_encoding()` call must be followed up with an equal number
 * of `reset_mbstring_encoding()` calls.
 *
 * @since 3.7.0
 *
 * @see reset_mbstring_encoding()
 *
 * @param bool $reset Optional. Whether to reset the encoding back to a previously-set encoding.
 *                    Default false.
 */
function mbstring_binary_safe_encoding( $reset = false ) {
    static $encodings = array();
    static $overloaded = null;

    if ( is_null( $overloaded ) )
        $overloaded = function_exists( 'mb_internal_encoding' ) && ( ini_get( 'mbstring.func_overload' ) & 2 );

    if ( false === $overloaded )
        return;

    if ( ! $reset ) {
        $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
        array_push( $encodings, $encoding );
        mb_internal_encoding( 'ISO-8859-1' );
    }

    if ( $reset && $encodings ) {
        $encoding = array_pop( $encodings );
        mb_internal_encoding( $encoding );
    }
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a string is utf8 encoded.
 *
 * NOTE: This function checks for 5-Byte sequences, UTF8
 *       has Bytes Sequences with a maximum length of 4.
 *
 * @author bmorel at ssi dot fr (modified)
 * @since 1.2.1
 *
 * @param string $str The string to be checked
 * @return bool True if $str fits a UTF-8 model, false otherwise.
 */
function seems_utf8($str) {
    mbstring_binary_safe_encoding();
    $length = strlen($str);
    reset_mbstring_encoding();
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $c = ord($str[$i]);
        if ($c < 0x80) $n = 0; # 0bbbbbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xE0) == 0xC0) $n=1; # 110bbbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xF0) == 0xE0) $n=2; # 1110bbbb
        elseif (($c & 0xF8) == 0xF0) $n=3; # 11110bbb
        elseif (($c & 0xFC) == 0xF8) $n=4; # 111110bb
        elseif (($c & 0xFE) == 0xFC) $n=5; # 1111110b
        else return false; # Does not match any model
        for ($j=0; $j<$n; $j++) { # n bytes matching 10bbbbbb follow ?
            if ((++$i == $length) || ((ord($str[$i]) & 0xC0) != 0x80))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * Reset the mbstring internal encoding to a users previously set encoding.
 *
 * @see mbstring_binary_safe_encoding()
 *
 * @since 3.7.0
 */
function reset_mbstring_encoding() {
    mbstring_binary_safe_encoding( true );
}
```

**example**:

```
echo remove_accents('Želda'); // Zelda
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use the `[:alnum:]` character class that contains only ascii letters and digits:

```
if (preg_match('/[^\p{Arabic}[:alnum:]]/u', $name))
```

If you want to allow digits from other languages:

```
if (preg_match('/[^\p{Arabic}a-z\d]/ui', $name))
```

Comment: let say i only want to prevent users from adding characters with accents for englih letters forget about arabic !